# How to extract part of the name of a variable as a string in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I have the following code in `PHP`:

```
$groupA = Array($russiapoints, $arabiapoints, $egyptpoints, $uruguaypoints);
rsort($groupA);//sort
$Awinner = $groupA[0];
$Arunner = $groupA[1];
```

Is there something I can put in between lines 2 and 3 in order to extract the variable names from the array and display them in a separate array?

Want to briefly point out I have very little previous knowledge of PHP and so please don't make any assumptions about my knowledge.

Comment: please add sample values of all variables as well as what expected data you want at the end[add sample output].It will make your question more clear and easy to answer

Comment: Please add more details about the variables $russiapoints, $arabiapoints etc.... Post some sample values for these variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written your array would not contain original names of the variables, only their values.

You would need to track that information explicitly, for example as array keys. For a persistent set hardcoding it would probably be good enough:

```php
$groupA = [
'russia'  => $russiapoints, 
'arabia'  => $arabiapoints, 
'egypt'   => $egyptpoints, 
'uruguay' => $uruguaypoints,
];

// if you want to retrieve just keys later

$keys = array_keys( $groupA );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to maintain a scorecard for the teams in Group A and then to find the winner and runner up in the list. To accomplish this, I would suggest you record the scorecard in the following structure.

```
$groupA = [
    [
        'name' => 'Russia',
        'points' => 12
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'China',
        'points' => 11,
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'France',
        'points' => 20,
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'USA',
        'points' => 10,
    ]
];
```

Now, we can process this array to find out the winner (the team with the highest score) and runner up (the team with the second highest score).  For that purpose, we will need to sort the array in reverse order based on the score. I have added a function to do this.

```
function comparePoints($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['points'] == $b['points']) {
        return 0;
    }
        return $a['points'] < $b['points'] ? 1 : -1;
}
```

and sorted my array with this function.

```
usort($groupA, 'comparePoints');
```

Now the array has the team with the highest points in the first position. I will find the winner, first runner up and second runner as follows.

```
$winner = array_shift($groupA);// first one in the array
$firstRunnerUp = array_shift($groupA); // second one in the array
$secondRunnerUp = array_shift($groupA); // third one in the array
```

Now just try `print_r($winner);`. The output will be

```
Array
(
    [name] => France
    [points] => 20
)
```

Note: I haven't considered the case if two teams have the same points. You will need to find a solution to that problem.

Read more about [uasort](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php)

Read more about [array_shift](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$groupA = compact('russiapoints', 'arabiapoints', 'egyptpoints', 'uruguaypoints');
arsort($groupA);//sort
$Awinner = key($groupA);next($groupA);
$Arunner = key($groupA);next($groupA);
```

and so on.